# How to reformat an Excel file to place gene symbols in consecutive cells in a single column

Tags: excel, csv

I have downloaded a tsv file from a bioinformatics website (http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/search.jsp). The gene symbols list is not properly formatted on opening the downloaded file in Excel (yellow highlight). The gene names/symbols are comma separated but have all been placed in the same cell. How do I reformat this spreadsheet so that I get a conventional spreadsheet of genes in separate cells, and in a single column in Excel? In the 3rd figure, the expanded gene list has a gap. I'm not sure the reason for this and whether it can simply be 'cut' from a reformatted spreadsheet? Many thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Text into columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)? After that you can use a [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027) to "flip" it.

Comment: How exactly are you opening the file in Excel? have you tried different options in the Import Text Wizard?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Hi, I visited the webpage in the first figure and searched genesets using 'HSIAO_HOUSEKEEPING_GENES' in the 'keywords' box. Then in the 'Select An Action' dropdown just below, I selected 'Export Selected Gene Sets As .TSV'.  I just played around with the different options in the Import Text wizard and used the TRANSPOSE function as suggested by Evil Blue Monkey. Bit different on a Mac vs Windows. For Mac, using Paste Special > Transpose worked for me. I have most of the genes in a single column now and only a bit of tidying up to do. Thanks Both!